# passing parameters between views and controllers ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, parameters

i have this form nested in view 'A'

```
<div>
<%if current_user%> 
    <%=form_for(ModelB.new) do |f|%>
      <%if (params[:param_to_check].present?)%>
        <%f.hidden_field "param1",:value=> @modelA.id%>
        <%f.hidden_field "param2",:value=> current_user.id%>
      <%end%>
    render button
    <%end%>
<%else%>
    render other butotn
<%end%>

</div>
```

and this 'find' in Bs_controller:

```
@modelA=ModelA.find_by_id(params[:param1])
  :option_from_specific_gem=> -(@modelA.wanted_value).abs
```

when i look to the params passed to the Bs_controller i see:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"some_hash=", "utf8"=>"✓", "y"=>"42", "x"=>"144"}
```

and i need to pass the hidden_field's valies to Bs_controller.

thx for the atention :)

here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/rmatuoka/dd6904809cf89cf916f7

Comment: is current_user set? Does params[:param_to_check] have a value? Are the hidden fields there in the rendered HTML?

Comment: `<% f.hidden_field "param1",:value=> @modelA.id %>` should probably be `<%= f.hidden_field "param1",:value=> @modelA.id %>`, as you have it, it won't render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some comments, I'm gonna go ahead and make them into an answer.

There are 3 possible things. Assuming it's not a typo, you aren't currently outputting the hidden fields to the HTML. You need to us `<%= %>` to output the result.

```
<%= f.hidden_field "param1",:value=> @modelA.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field "param2",:value=> current_user.id %>
```

This is likely the issue. Otherwise I'd guess either current_user or params[:param_to_check] is nil.

Comment: thanks, i noticed that just before reading your answer, lol. when i came back to delete i saw your answer and decided to leave it here to others heedless like me :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `param1` and `param2` to your list of permitted parameters.  In your controller, you should have something like:

```
def modela_params
  params.require(:modela).permit(:x, :y, :param1, :param2)
end
```

Comment: He's tagged with Rails 3, and made no mention of strong parameters, so chances are this is not the case.